# Passing two variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a selet function where I pass two variables. The table and where.

However, whatever I put for where it always displays id = 1.

Could this be because it is recognising that id has a value and setting it to 1 or am I completely off the mark here?

The function is below:

```
public function select($table, $where){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
        return $this->processRowSet($result, true);
    }
    return $this->processRowSet($result);
}
```

The call to the function is:

```
$rowSet = $db->select('users','username = wayne');
```

Or is it the way I am setting username in the parameter?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` in the meantime to find out what's wrong. Then enclose SQL string values in appropriate quotes.

Comment: `return $this->processRowSet($result, mysql_num_rows($result) == 1);` would save on line.

Comment: You need to quote the value in your where parameter `"username = 'wayne'"`, also it would be a good idea to use the database libraries native escaping mechanism to sanitize any data coming from an untrusted source.

Comment: THanks for the quick replies. Thank you also OrangePill.. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

username is a String then it is necessary to write

```
$rowSet = $db->select('users','username = "wayne"');
```